# How can I use Bootswatch in an Angular project?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootswatch

I have an Angular project in which I want to use Bootswatch. But I don't know how to install it, I first tried to install the module with:

```
npm i bootswatch
```

Then in the angular.json file I did the following:

```
 "styles: [
    "bootswatch/dist/lux/bootstrap.min.css",
    "node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css",
    "src/styles.css". ]
```

But it doesn't work for me, I still see the default Bootstrap theme, what can I do?

Comment: check your index.html to find any link ref referring to bootstrap?

Comment: Working link :https://therichpost.com/how-to-add-and-run-bootswatch-in-angular-12-application/

Answer (score 0):

Angular. json has two modifications to 'serve' and 'build'. Please check if only one is modified